# Can we cache parsed XML data on iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I want to know is it possible to cache the parsed XML data? And what about asynchronous parsing as we cache images in iPhone?

Comment: what is it that you want exactly?

Comment: see in my case when I press a button , app starts parsing and after the parsing done then only second view displayed. What I want to do is when I click on button the next view should be displayed regardless of parsing and when parsing done then display the data !

Comment: Pls post your code if you want to get something you require

Comment: yet I didn't start it but ya I've done asynchronous downloading of images.. so I want to know can I apply the same functionality to xml parsing or not ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a NSOperation for the purpose of asynchronous parsing. You should subclass the NSOperation and create your parser. Use an NSOperationQueue to hold NSOperation. You can refer [Top paid Sample app from apple.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/TopPaid/Introduction/Intro.html)

Comment: and what if my next view contains the UITabelView which is fill up by the parsed data ? will app crashed due to numbers of row would be based on data !

Comment: No, it won't crash. But you should manage it accordingly. You can refer to the Top Paid sample app. It is demonstrating the same scenario of yours.

Comment: Also you can cache the parsed xml data using Core Data API.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you store your parsed data in sqlite database??